# How to have R Shiny keep running when user navigates away?

Tags: r, shiny

How can I have an R Shiny app continue running even if the user navigates away from the page?

A simplified example is included below, recording one data point every half second.  The app adds points as long as the webpage is viewed, stops when the user navigates away (the gap) and continues if they navigate back.  Is there a way to have it run without the gap?

[image: wave plot]

Example code:

```
library(shiny)

starttime<-as.POSIXct(Sys.time())

timeconst=5
time<-as.numeric(difftime(  as.POSIXct(Sys.time()),starttime, units="secs"))
mydata<-data.frame(time=Sys.time(), sin( time / timeconst ))

runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(headerPanel("Sine wave"),NULL,
                       mainPanel(plotOutput("sinePlot"))),
  server =function(input, output, session) {
    autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(500, session)
    output$sinePlot <- renderPlot({
      autoInvalidate()
      time<-as.numeric(difftime(  as.POSIXct(Sys.time()) , starttime, units="secs") )
      mydata<<-rbind(mydata,data.frame(time=Sys.time(), sin( time / timeconst )) )
      plot(mydata)
      })}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the documentation for [reactiveTimer](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactiveTimer.html). The general behavior is that you want a timer that's bound to the user's session, so that when the user leaves your applications doesn't continue doing work on their behalf eternally.

However, if you want the timer to continue running after the session exits, provide `NULL` to the `session` argument in `reactiveTimer`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  I changed `reactiveTimer(500, session)` to `reactiveTimer(500, session=NULL)` in the above code and it had no effect---there's still a gap when the user navigates away.  Does it work for you?